# Capitalisation - hyphenated proper noun

Tags: capitalization

I came across an organisation called Task Force on Climate-related Financial Disclosures (TCFD). From what I've learned from style guides and StackExchange contributors, I understand that the second part of a hyphenated word should be capitalised unless it is preceded by a prefix or it is itself a suffix, so it would be 'Five-Star' but 'Anti-corruption'. I am wondering why, in that case, that 'related' would be in lower case.

Can someone please enlighten me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that the organization is not using the same style guides as you, or perhaps not any?